# Question about Non-Schengen to Schengen passport validity

Tags: schengen, passports, netherlands, sweden

My sister has tickets to visit me in Sweden from the USA in a few weeks and has just realized that her passport expires in March 2017. Schengen laws require a passport has to be valid 3 months after departure date, which is fine for visiting Sweden, but she has to connect in the Netherlands at Schiphol airport, which requires at least 6-months validity.

From what I can find, it's the destination country that decides the validity,  right? She isn't actually stopping in The Netherlands, only passing through the airport. Schiphol is listed as a Schengen airport, so which law trumps the other? We're trying to figure out if she needs to drive a whole day to get a 1-day passport renewal or if she'll be able to get through Schiphol into Sweden which accepts her passport without issue.

I appreciate anyone who can enlighten me further. Thanks!

Comment: She's not stopping in NL, but she will be clearing passport control there.

Comment: What is your source for the Netherlands requiring 6 months of passport validity? That's not what the Schengen rules say.

Comment: @phoog I know she will because she's going Non-Schegen to Schengen, but who's requirements do those people checking abide by? Schengen or Country?

Comment: @HenningMakholm https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/netherlands.html PASSPORT VALIDITY: at least 6 months beyond planned date of departure from the Schengen area.

Comment: Would be interesting to know where the State Department got this info. As far as EU law is concerned, that's not up to either country, it's defined in the Schengen Borders Code, which, as an EU *regulation*, is directly binding for both Sweden and the Netherlands. From this perspective, neither are free to set their own rules and it does not make sense to ask which country's rules apply. And that's also why we struggle to give a staightforward answer!

Comment: @Relaxed Haha Yea I have been telling her that it should be Schegen law that matters, but it's so unclear and confusing. :)

Comment: Of course if the Netherlands disregards current law and really forces airlines to check for 6-month validity or worse denies entry based on this "rule", your recourses are limited.

Comment: Thinking about it, it's possible the State's Department six months comes from three months after departure + 90 days (the maximum stay) so about six months after entry. If you can somehow support your intent not to use the full 90 days and to return before, it should be no problem, the requirement is really 3 months after intended date of departure, nothing else.

Comment: @Relaxed the problem is that the US government has incorrect (perhaps outdated) information.  It took a little doing to find the real information on an NL government site, but I did, and it specifies 3 months.  The US also *recommends* six months (because of 90 days maximum stay + 3 months extra validity), so that could be another source of confusion.

Comment: @Relaxed but the state department does actually say "passport *should be* valid for six months" (emphasis added); not *must be.*  At https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/netherlands.html.  As a result, if you Google "Netherlands entry requirements" the info box says 6 months.

Comment: Just to clarify something: Your sister _will_ be visiting The Netherlands. The in-Schengen part of the airport is not an international transfer area, rather it's like a domestic terminal at a US airport. Once she clears passport control at Schiphol, she will be in Dutch territory, and governed by Dutch laws and regulations. If there were anything that barred her entry to the Netherlands (which doesn't seem to be the case here), she wouldn't be able to transfer in Amsterdam.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There will be no problem.

While the US Department of State claims that the Netherlands requires six months' validity, the actual requirement is three months:

> That passport or travel document must cover your intended stay and remain valid for at least three months after your intended date of departure.

Source: http://www.the-netherlands.org/shared/products-and-services/products-and-services/schengen-visa/entering-the-netherlands-or-the-schengen-area-without-a-visa

Comment: Thanks! I'll tell her not to worry about renewing until she's back from the trip.

Answer (score 9):

Sweden and The Netherlands are both in the Schengen area and follow its common rules, the [Schengen Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32016R0399), according to which the requirement a traveler must satisfy is that

> (Art 6.1.a) they are in possession of a valid travel document entitling the holder to cross the border satisfying the following criteria:
>   (i) its validity shall extend at least **three months** after the intended date of departure from the territory of the Member States. In a justified case of emergency, this obligation may be waived;
>   (ii) it shall have been issued within the previous 10 years;

There doesn't seem to be any provision for the Netherlands to require a longer period of validity than these three months.